# wsgi + django - permissions for files

Tags: django, apache, wsgi

when deploying with `wsgi` and `django`, what should be files' permissions in order to get the application running? I've `read+execute` for `others` but once i remove execute permission to the files seems like lord `www-data` does not have permission for some things.

```
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

I've tried adding back `o+x` for the wsgi file but seems futile. question is, what are the files requiring execute permission?

Comment: Is this really problem because of file permissions? My blog have `-rw-r--r--` for files and `drwxr-xr-x` for folders and that's it - everything works just fine. What about `chown www-data:www-data * -R`?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the only consideration needs to be that *every* directory from the root to the `server.wsgi` file must be readable by the `wsgi` container (such as Apache or uwsgi).  If you're going to have writeable services, then the file or directory into which you write must be writeable by the `wsgi` container process, as well as the parent directory.  (This is a common gotcha with sqlite-- the directory which contains sqlite must likewise be writeable by `wsgi` process.  But you're not using sqlite.)

Find out what the `wsgi` process is running as, both its user and group status.  Then, from that directory, slowly back out, parent directory by parent directory, running an `ls -ld` on the child, and make sure that it is accessible by the process.